# NSView layer shadow draws on subviews, not view itself

Tags: cocoa, calayer, nsview, shadow

I'm trying to set a shadow on the `layer` of an `NSView`, but the layer is being drawn on the subviews of my view, not the view itself. What can be causing this?

The view in question and all its subviews are layer-backed. All but one of the subviews are buttons (`NSButton`) with images - the other one is a custom view that renders via `drawRect:`.

```
self.layer.shadowColor = [[NSColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.9].CGColor;
self.layer.shadowRadius = 2;
self.layer.shadowOffset = NSMakeSize(0, -1);
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9;
```

I've also tried setting the shadow via an `NSShadow`, with the same outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that if you set a shadow on an `NSView`'s `layer`, it only draws on that view if the view has a `drawRect:` implementation that draws something non-transparent. Otherwise it draws on all the view's subviews.

Weird.